# Rename variable in all commits on a given branch

Tags: git

My repo looks something like this:

```
         (develop) D - E - F - G - H
                  /
(master) A - B - C
```

In the course of a code review (where I propose to merge `develop` into `master`), I was asked to change the name of a variable that was introduced in `D` (e.g. change `foo` to `bar`) .  If I were patient, I could look through all the commits in `D`, `E`, `F`, `G` and `H`, create fixup commits for each and then rebase away `foo` entirely so that only `bar` remains in the history.

It seems like there should be a better way.  A little googling makes me believe that I *should* be able to make something work with `git filter-branch`, but as I'm re-writing history and all -- I'd prefer to be able to get it right the first time instead of doing a bunch of weird stuff and messing up my repo entirely...

A few helpful constraints for the purposes of this problem:

- We *can* assume that the names `foo` and `bar` are globally unique.  e.g. if I did a `sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' FILE`, I'll be left with the result I want without worrying about names like `foobar` being incorrectly translated to `barbar`.
- I'm using OS-X -- So POSIX compliant invocations of shell utilities are preferred (though I can work to translate from GNU variants if I must)

Comment: Why change history? Simply commit again on develop with foo replaced with bar, then merge.

Comment: @GreenAsJade -- If all the commits are clean, then I can revert any one of them that turns out to be bad and (hopefully) everything else still works.  e.g. consider the case where a bug is introduced in `F`.  If I make a new commit that renames everything, I can't simply revert `F` without having to work through a bunch of conflicts.

Comment: @mgilson IMHO it's a little expensive to keep all commits "clean" (considering that revert is not common in my life). And a revertible commit may become non-revertible after more commits are introduced. Keeping merge-commits revertible may be easier.

Comment: @Jokester -- Yeah.  If it ends up being more trouble than it's worth I'll go ahead and make another commit and be done with it.  I _do_ also `git rebase` frequently to clean up dirty commits before merging to master and I find it quite helpful when going back over my repo's history trying to figure out what changed where (and why).  The less noise I have in my history the happier I am (perhaps that's a more compelling use-case than the `revert` case?).  I guess I'm just hoping that a git master will drop a 1-liner like: `git filter-branch --tree-filter 'sed -i "s/foo/bar"' -- develop` ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were already quite close with your attempt.

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'sed -i "s/foo/bar/g" $FILES'  D^..H HEAD
```

assuming you are on your `develop` branch and you replace `D` and `H` with the commit index.

If you mess something up, there is always the reflog. You can also branch before or hand-write the commit reference before as a safeguard. I would recommend performing this in a separate branch, however.

`$FILES` here is a list of files containing your variable. I guess you could replace it with `$(git grep --name-only foo)`. I didn't try it however, and you might have to escape the `$` symbol. The simplest option is to hand-write a list of files there, of course.

Edit: just tried. It works without escaping. `sed` however fails if there is no input file, aborting the process. You also get a copy of your old refs in `.git/refs/original/`, so you might need to add `-f` after `git filter-branch` if this is not your first attempt, in order to overwrite the copy.

Comment: Nice.  This is what I was looking for.  It'd be nice if there was a way to just get the files in each commit instead of needing to specify `FILES` explicitly, but this was good enough for me for the time being :-).

Comment: This is what `$(git grep --name-only foo)` was supposed to do :)

Comment: Wouldn't that search the entire repo -- rather than just the changed files?  I suppose that in this case it would probably not make much a difference, but it _could_ in the case where there were untouched files that contained the word `foo` that I wanted to preserve.

Comment: You are right, I didn't see it this way. Then, how about `$(git diff --name-only --diff-filter=AMC HEAD HEAD^)` instead? (AMC is for added, copied and modified files, since we don't really want deleted - or other - files). See [git diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff).

Comment: That might work :-).  I'll have to give it a try the next time I run into this.  I suppose that `FILES=$(git diff --name-only HEAD sha_C)` would probably be an easy way to get the file-list as well ...

Answer (score 0):

The newer [`git-filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) might be preferable and have built-in replace-text functionality.

I found the instructions a bit unclear and the github page doesn't even mention that `replace-text` exits.

```
  --replace-text EXPRESSIONS_FILE
                     A file with expressions that, if found, will be
                     replaced. By default, each expression is treated as
                     literal text, but 'regex:' and 'glob:' prefixes are
                     supported. You can end the line with '==>' and some
                     replacement text to choose a replacement choice other
                     than the default of '***REMOVED***'.
```

**DISCLAIMER BEGIN**

The tool printed a big warning the first time I ran the tool (even when `--refs` was specified..):

```
Aborting: Refusing to destructively overwrite repo history since
this does not look like a fresh clone.
  (expected freshly packed repo)
Please operate on a fresh clone instead.  If you want to proceed
anyway, use --force.
```

By this they mean that when running *without* `--partial` they wipe stashes, the reflog and a bunch of other things.

To my understanding and experience is that it's safe to use when specifying `--partial` and `--refs`. (`--partial` is implied by `--refs`, but better safe than sorry?)

**DISCLAIMER END**

Example:

```
$ cat renames.txt
regex:\bthis_is_a_tyop\b==>this_is_a_typo

$ git-filter-repo --replace-text renames.txt --refs $(git merge-base master HEAD)..HEAD --partial
```

It was not obvious/clear to me that this would only replace text in the files the commits touched, but this is luckily the case.

---

In general I would love if someone could update the docs for git-filter-repo to be more friendly to the more "mundane" use-cases (not fully destructive). (the wording in the --replace-text docs for instance indicate that this option's existence is due to redactions, not git gymnastics when working with branches for instance)